# componentWillMount change className of another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have my app component where everything is pulled in such as Nav, Footer, pages and sub pages.  I'd like for one sub page to change the look of the nav when you enter it.

I have `document.body.className = 'countdown'` which works just fine for the body when you call said component, but I can't seem to change the nav component by doing, say `document.nav.className ='someClass'`

Here is how my React app is setup:

```
      render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <Nav style={{zIndex: 10000}} navClass={this.state.navClass} />
          <Route path="/welcome" component={Content}/>
          <Route path="/home" component={Content}/>
          <Route path="/projects" component={Projects}/>
          <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
          <Route path="/blog" component={Blog}/>
          <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
          <Route path="/projectpages/galaxy" component={Galaxy}/>
          <Route path="/projectpages/stardates" component={StarDates}/>
          <Footer style={{zIndex: 10000}} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I want that when you call `stardates` that it would be able to change the class of `Nav` (it has a class `NavClear`.

In `stardates` I have

```
    class StarDates extends React.Component {

  style = {
    default: { width: 300 },
    onFocus: { borderBottom: '1px solid green' },
    onError: { borderBottom: '1px solid red' }
  }

  check = newValue => newValue < 10
  format = value => `${value} $`

  componentWillMount() {
    document.body.className = 'countdown'
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.body.className = ''
  }
  render() {
    return (...
```

I have tried various things with and combed through StackO/Google coming up with no answers I can figure out.  Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: You could pass a function from your `App` to your `StarDates` component, that will change the state of the `navClass` in the `App` component, so that the Nav className changes

Comment: I didn't think of that, thanks.  I'm still very weak on React and it's a slow progress (like writing this function will be a challenge for me) but I'm up for the task.  Any particular documentation you could point towards to help out with that?  Thanks!

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html that's a really good place to start. Also `Lifting state up` also from the docs, helps a lot